# Need help in vba populating data based on a certain column

Tags: excel, vba

This is how row 1028 look like

| Yield Curve Name | Term | Term Type | Current Qtr | Previous Qtr | Variance | Variance % | Currency | Blank Column | VAR TOLERANCE FLAG | YC ABOVE TOLERANCE | Variance in Abs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAD_CAD_OIS | 1D | Days | 0.71537 | 4.7487 | -4.0339 | -84.935% | CAD |  | VAR GT TOLERANCE | YC within tolerance | 0.84 |

requirement is to use VBA code to populate the "YC ABOVE TOLERANCE" column based on the values in the "VAR TOLERANCE FLAG" column for a given Excel sheet named "QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks." If any term point for a specific yield curve has the value "VAR GT TOLERANCE" in the "VAR TOLERANCE FLAG" column, then all term points for that curve should be marked as "YC above tolerance" in the "YC ABOVE TOLERANCE" column. If the term point does not breach the threshold, it should be marked as "YC within tolerance." The code should dynamically handle different curves in column A and work with the entire dataset in the sheet.

here is the code i have written but its not serving the purpose

Here is the vba code

```vb
Sub PopulateYCToleranceFlagField()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    
    Dim MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter As Long
    Dim MyVarToleranceCell As Range
    Dim MyLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyLastYieldCurveGTTolerance As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet reference
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks")
    
    ' Find the last used row in column A
    MyLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Initialize the row counter
    MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter = 2 ' Assuming the data starts from row 2 in column A
    
    ' Initialize the variable to track the last yield curve
    MyLastYieldCurveGTTolerance = " "
    
    ' Loop through the data in column A
    Do While ws.Cells(MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter, 1).Value <> ""
        If ws.Cells(MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter, 1).Value <> MyLastYieldCurveGTTolerance Then
            Application.StatusBar = MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter & " of " & MyLastRow - 1 & " rows - Yield curve ==> " & ws.Cells(MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter, 1).Value
            DoEvents
            
            ' Check if any cell in column J has "VAR GT TOLERANCE"
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 10), ws.Cells(MyLastRow - 1, 10)), "VAR GT TOLERANCE") > 0 Then
                ' If true, populate "YC above Tolerance" for the entire yield curve in column K
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 11), ws.Cells(MyLastRow - 1, 11)).Value = "YC above Tolerance"
            End If
            
            ' Update the last yield curve
            MyLastYieldCurveGTTolerance = ws.Cells(MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter, 1).Value
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next row
        MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter = MyYieldCurveCellRowCounter + 1
    Loop
    
    ' Clear the status bar
    Application.StatusBar = " "
End Sub
```

Comment: Each yield curve has multiple term points starting from 1 day, 1 week, 1 month and goes till 360 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Load data into an array
- Check `YC ABOVE TOLERANCE` status and store in Dictionary object
- Populate column K all at once

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo3()
    Dim i As Long, arrData, arrK(), oSht as Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, oDic, sKey As String
    Const KEYWORD = "VAR GT TOLERANCE"
    Const SHT_NAME = "QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks" ' modify as needed
    Set oSht = Sheets(SHT_NAME)
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = oSht.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Value
    ReDim arrK(1 To LastRow - 1, 1 To 1)
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Not oDic.exists(sKey) Then oDic(sKey) = False
        If UCase(arrData(i, 10)) = KEYWORD Then
            oDic(sKey) = True
        End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If oDic(arrData(i, 1)) Then
            arrK(i, 1) = "YC above tolerance"
        Else
            arrK(i, 1) = "YC within tolerance"
        End If
    Next i
    oSht.Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Value = arrK
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i would like to know one from this data i am creating a pivot table and then plotting a graph and whenever i refresh the pivot the line graph that i plot for variance detaches itself from secondary axis , is there a way for a premanent fix ?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) I would suggest you post a new question. SO users will help you out. Please clarify the meaning of `variance detaches itself from secondary axis` in your new post. Maybe a screenshot is helpful.

Comment: sorry mate the code worked fine till row 1028 post which i can see a variance in % which is -84% but its still showing "YC within Tolerance" for that term point and for the entire curve i.e. CA_CAD_OIS

Comment: can we do something that it handles positive as well as negative variances as well, i dont want the code to touch column J as column J already has a formula which is =IFERROR(IF(ABS(G7)>$J2,"VAR GT TOLERANCE","VAR WITHIN TOLERANCE"),"ERROR") where J2 is the cell where i put the tolerance level say 20%

Comment: I can't say how to fix it without knowing about row 1028. `i dont want the code to touch column J` it is doable.

Comment: Just after the negative variance, all the rows are set as "YC within tolerance"

Comment: I've update the code to consolidate two arrays into one.

Comment: ok it works fine as intended only when  i run it from the same sheet by adding a button and assigning a macro but when i try to run the same from a different sheet named "Dashboard" by adding a button it run but gives "YC within tolerance" even where the variance is above 30%

Comment: May I know what's the name of `the same sheet`? Is it fixed?

Comment: so the sheet where the table is present with column k is named as "QRM_YC_QoQ_Checks"

Comment: You need to qualify all cell(s) reference with the sheet object. See updated code.

Comment: getting srcipt out of range at this line :   If UCase(arrData(i, 10)) = KEYWORD Then

Comment: Is `arrData = oSht.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Value` in your code?

Comment: now its populating "YC within tolerance" even for those where the variance is above 30% or where i have "VAR GT TOLERANC"

Comment: yes arrData = oSht.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Value  i had changed  If UCase(arrData(i, 10)) to i,1 as it was showing out of range while using 10

Comment: Pleases test my code first and then revise it as your expected.  It is `"A2:J"` instead of `"A2:A"`

Comment: i received the error while testing your updated code only

Comment: Please try `Demo3`. I haven't changed its name for the last revise. I guess you used mixed code. I've tested the code with the sample data in your post.

Comment: `arrData = oSht.Range("A2:J" & LastRow).Value` loads column A:J into an array. `arrData(i, 10)` is a cell in col J and `arrData(i, 1)` is a cell in col A.